# Interpolation through Newton polynomials

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I attempted to solve the problem, and would like a solution to compare to.

The question is:

> Write a function that determines the (n-1)th order Newton polynomial and interpolates for a
> set of values. The inputs of your function should be: a vector of x values, a corresponding
> vector of y values, and a vector of values to interpolate. Your outputs should be the
> coefficients of the polynomial (as a vector, [a1 a2 ···an]) and the corresponding function
> values for the interpolation. Thoroughly comment your code to show that you
> know what you are doing.

My attempt is:

```
function yint = Newtint(x,y,xx)
    n = length(x);

    if length(y)~=n, error('x and y must be same length'); end
    
    b = zeros(n,n);
    b(:,1) = y(:); % the (:) ensures that y is a column vector.
    
    for j = 2:n
        for i = 1:n-j+1
            b(i,j) = (b(i+1,j-1)-b(i,j-1))/(x(i+j-1)-x(i));
        end
    end
    
    xt = 1;
    yint = b(1,1);
    
    for j = 1:n-1
        xt = xt*(xx-x(j));
        yint = yint+b(1,j+1)*xt;
    end
    
    
    % input:
    % x = independent variable
    % y = dependent variable
    % xx = value of independent variable at which
    % interpolation is calculated
    % output:
    % yint = interpolated value of dependent variable
    % compute the finite divided differences in the form of a
    % difference table
```

Comment: Show us your attempt then.

Comment: I added my attempt to the question, but im pretty sure its off by a bit

Comment: It lacks the thorough documentation that is required by the question though.

Comment: Added documentation

Comment: What is the problem with your solution? Does it produce an error message? Does it produce wrong results? Please be explicit about  your question, see [ask].  Asking for a solution to your homework is not going to fly, but we're more than happy to help you with specific issues you're facing.

Comment: Even though matlab doesn't require you to indent your code, I strongly suggest you do so. Having properly indented code makes it much easier to read and understand, since you can easily figure out what line belongs in what block of code by just looking at it.

Comment: Your code runs if you add a point at line 19 to muliplcation